# how to Call webroot php file in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

How to call webroot php file in cakephp. For an example `http://localhost/cakephp/test.php` is openings . Like that I want to open `http://localhost/cakephp/abc.php.`

Answer (score 1):

Simple Create a file project/app/webroot/abc.php

Replace something

```
<?php
   // do something 
?>
```

Then call it

```
 Http://localhost/cakephp/abc.php
```

Comment: but its redirect into controller . I got the solution . I have to create a library in lib/cake. I just copied and pasted Test folder in lib/cake. then rename it as abc . Now  Http://localhost/cakephp/abc.php is working file . WE have to create lib or else its redirected to controller . Thanks a lot for reply .

Comment: @user3824319 No, just no. If _that_ is necessary, then something is fundamentally wrong with your setup. By default all files in the webroot directory are accessible.

Comment: @user3824319 you should not touch library files.

Answer (score 0):

In your ctp file just redirect to /abc.php

Webroot PHP files are directly accessible in ctp files, for redirect.